# Swift 3 returns "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error for facebook login

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swift3, facebook-login

I am new to Swift, getting error for [.publicProfile].

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error

Code:

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.native;
    loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile], viewController: self) { (loginResult) in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions) \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
```

Method Signature:

```
loginManager.logIn(<#T##permissions: [ReadPermission]##[ReadPermission]#>, viewController: <#T##UIViewController?#>, completion: <#T##((LoginResult) -> Void)?##((LoginResult) -> Void)?##(LoginResult) -> Void#>)
```

Comment: What is the signature for loginManager.logIn()? That probably your answer too.

Comment: updated question with signature.

Answer (score 3):

In the last updated FacebookLogin API you should add parameter name before the first parameter:

```
loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile], ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it resolved as I was creating this method in Manager which subclass of `NSObject` class. 
So passing self for `viewController` was giving me issue. So i fixed by passing fromViewController instead of self. That's all.

```
 func facebookLogin(fromViewController:UIViewController)  {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.native;

        loginManager.logIn([.publicProfile], viewController: fromViewController) { (loginResult) in
            switch loginResult {
            case .failed(let error):
                print(error)
            case .cancelled:
                print("User cancelled login.")
            case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                print("Logged in \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions) \(accessToken)")
            }
        }

    }
```